# how to find a line in a text with specific term in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I couldnt find a response for this in spark scala,

please look at the detail,

I have an output text that contains list of topic with their weight like this:(this has been achieved using lda on a document)

```
TOPIC_0;connection;0.030922248292319265
TOPIC_0;pragmatic;0.02690878152282403
TOPIC_0;Originator;0.02443295327258558
TOPIC_0;check;0.022290036662386385
TOPIC_0;input;0.020578378303486064
TOPIC_0;character;0.019718375317755072
TOPIC_0;wide;0.017389396600966833
TOPIC_0;load;0.016898979702795396
TOPIC_0;Pretty;0.014923624938546124
TOPIC_0;soon;0.014731449663492822
```

I want to go through each topic and find the first sentence related to this topic in a file.

I tried something like this but I can not make my mind about this to filter:

```
    topic.foreach { case (term, weight) =>
    val filePath = "data/20_news/sci.BusinessandFinance/14147"
    val lines = sc.textFile(filePath)
    val words = lines.flatMap(x => x.split(' '))
    val sentence = words.filter(w => words.contains(term))

     }
```

the last line for filtering is incorrect,

**for example:**

my text file is like this:

```
input for the program should be checked. the connection between two part is pretty simple.
```

so it should extract the first sentence for topic :"`input`"

any help or idea is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are filtering on your list of words and you should be filtering on lines.

This code: `words.contains(term)` doesn't really make sense since it returns true if the term appears in any of the words.

It would make more sense to write something like this:

```
w.contains(term)
```

So that at least your filter would only return the words that match the term.

However what you really want is to see if the `line` (ie sentence) contains the term.

```
topic.foreach { case (term, weight) =>
    val filePath = "data/20_news/sci.BusinessandFinance/14147"
    val lines = sc.textFile(filePath)
    val sentence = lines.filter(line => line.contains(term))
     }
```

It may be though that the lines need extra splitting (e.g. on full stops) to get the sentences.
You could add this step in like so:

```
topic.foreach { case (term, weight) =>
    val filePath = "data/20_news/sci.BusinessandFinance/14147"
    val lines = sc.textFile(filePath)
    val morelines = lines.flatMap(l => l.split(". "))
    val sentence = morelines.filter(line => line.contains(term))
     }
```

Comment: really thanks for your complete answer and time, but the problem is, when I wrote dows sentence.collect, and then print that to see the sentence if that is correct or not , it showing something like this      [Ljava.lang.String;@448090e7
[Ljava.lang.String;@2a1f244c
[Ljava.lang.String;@18ddd6b3
[Ljava.lang.String;@6e15ae7a
[Ljava.lang.String;@2be264a5
[Ljava.lang.String;@3e8bbb52

Comment: Actually I need the whole sentence that the term has been appeared, may I ask you to haave a look again

Comment: you need to convert to a List of Strings, instead of an Array of Strings like this: data.collect.foreach(arr => println(arr.toList))

Comment: very thanksss for your answer. the output is confusing cause I have "which company owns kraft foods? i heard it was a non-foods company"  , in the println for the sentence it shows "List(whic, compan, own, kraf, foods, , hear, i, wa, , non-food, company)", so why this is like this? many thanks for ur time

Comment: it seems it deleted the last literal in each word in the sentence

Answer (score 0):

val rddOnline = sc.textFile("/path/to/file")

val hasLine = rddOnline.map(line => line.contains("whatever it is"))

it will return true or false